# Using protractor selectors and a possible synchronisation issue

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm doing e2e tests fairly naively. The first two pages of the site are angular-less, so I'm using driver.findelement to get by them, with ignore synchronisation set to true:

```
  it('should go to login page on pressing button',function(){
    driver.get('http://localhost:54080/');
    driver.findElement(by.id('loginButton')).click();
    expect(driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('Account/Login');
  });
```

And so on. Upon reaching the angular-ish part (and no longer ignoring synchronisation), however, I want to be able to use the protractor selectors, like by model.

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.model('item.Title'))
```

Which I find gives me a synchronisation error:

```
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {...
```

I've tried many things and I'm doing very little in the tests timing-wise, it's mostly written in a vaguely functional style. I'm not polling anything, so it should be fairly simple and I'm almost convinced it's a timing or synchronisation issue, going off the general flavour of most of the documentation.

Comment: To update, the tests work when I set ignoresynchronisation to true - not sure what the repercussions of this might be.

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is waiting for all AngularJS $timeout and $http calls to complete before moving on to the next test. By default, it times out after 11 seconds (arbitrary, I know). If you're using $timeout for polling, or have extensive $http calls when the page first loads, then it's easy to hit this limit.

The way I solved the problem was to increase the `allScriptsTimeout` property in my protractor config to `30000` (30 seconds).

Comment: And don't forget to press F12 key to see what's happening at network layer during this delay.  It could help you understand a bit more about what's happening.